# Git alias to create a new branch, switch repository and create the same branch there

Tags: git, svn, github, version-control

I have 2 repositories, as our application exists of our basic product, and then an extended product for each client we have (I only work with 1 client, thus only 2 repositories).

When I make a new branch on the basic product repository, I want the same branch to be created on the extended product repository.

To do this, I created a git alias using:

git config --global alias.newbranch '!git checkout -b $0 central/branchName && cd ../ExtendedProduct && git checkout -b $0 central/branchName'

When I run this using:
git newbranch test, I get an exception saying ../ExtendedProduct is outside Repository.

I'm not sure if what I want is at all possible, but any help would be appreciated.

So basically:
Create branch on current repository -> switch repository -> create branch with same name on that repository.

Comment: Did the answer help you solve the problem? If yes, please mark it. And it will help others who have similar questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Git alias has some restrictions, but you can **use these commands directly**, such as

```
git checkout -b central/branchName && cd ../ExtendedProduct && git checkout -b central/branchName
```

Also, there is another way, you can **add ExtendedProduct as submodule** for your current repo by `git submodule add /path/for/ExtendedProduct`. And then use

```
git checkout -b central/branchName && git submodule foreach 'git checkout -b central/branchName'
```